# How to post form variables with javascript, just like a type="submit" button

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm a noobie programmer and I wonder how to properly submit a form with javascript.

I made some test code to show you what I mean:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['message']))
    {
        echo $_POST['message'];
    }
?>

<script>
    function formsubmit() 
    {
        document.getElementById('form').submit();           
    }
</script>

<form id="form" name="form" action="" method="post">
    <input id="message" name="message" value="hello world">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">
</form>

<a href="" onClick="formsubmit()">Click me</a><br/>
<input type="submit" onClick="formsubmit()" value="Click me">
```

When you push the "submit" button inside the   tags - the php code will echo "hello world".
When submitting the form with JS the values won't post to the page. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.
I've searched the whole afternoon for a solution, but cause of my lack of knowledge about programming I failed to find it.

Comment: Why use JavaScript when HTML will suffice? Just use Javascript to improve the users experience?

Comment: I am using JavaScript because my form has 100+ input fields. Those fields get populated based on a selection the user made. (This happens with J query & Ajax.) Then the user can modify every single input field and when clicking the javascript button, the form which contain 100+ inputs should post all those inputs to ittself and update the database with new + old data. Because there are 100+ input fields, I've made a navigation bar which contain buttons who are fixed on the screen. One of these buttons contains the "save changes" function which simply posts this big form to itsself.

Comment: This is rigorous - My passport application does not have that many entries. Even if - Why not break it down a little.

Comment: Cause I don't see any other way of creating it on a user friendly base. If you are interested I can show you my web-app and prehaps you could give some advise. Peace

Comment: When eating a cake why not try a mouthful at a time. Sometimes you do not need to have a mouthful of raisins nor cherries! Understand.

Comment: How is it user friendly asking 100 questions on the trot when some of those questions are supercilious?

Comment: Ok, let me explain. The user can fill in a word template which needs to be send to the employer every day. The word template has 100+ inputs that can be filled out. Now to make this easier I've created a web app so the user can make some selections and fill in max 10 inputs to fill out the complete report. This saves them allot of time! However, if they make a mistake, they are able to adjust it. Therefore they can go to the edit page which shows all the fields that can be filled out on the word template. I think this is the best way in case the user makes a mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Believe it or not, but the main problem lies here:

```
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">
```

If a form contains an input element with name (or id) of `submit` it will mask the `.submit()` method of the form element, because `.submit` will point to the button instead of the method. Just change it to this:

```
<input name="go" type="submit">
```

See also: [Notes for `form.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.submit#Notes)

The smaller problem is here:

```
<a href="" onClick="formsubmit()">Click me</a><br/>
```

An empty anchor will just request the same page again before calling `formsubmit()`. Just add `href="#"`.

Comment: PS: `<br/>` should be `<br>` without the slash.

Comment: <br /> is the proper format if you are trying to pass W3C validation because there is no closing </br> tag.

Comment: I also believe that you can't use `submit` as the name. `<input name="something_besides_submit" type="submit">` [**Look at this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QttUk/)

Comment: @rsmith84 - There shouldn't be a closing `<br>` tag: [W3C HTML5 Spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-br-element)

Comment: @Aust You're right! MDN only mentioned `id`, but it turns out that `name` exhibits the same problem. Thanks for spotting it :)

Comment: @Aust - In Google Chrome both of the `submit` button are working.

Comment: @Derek `<br>` has empty content model, ergo `<br />` for self closing tag.

Comment: Thank you very much Jack! Surprisingly, it works now. If I remember correctly, I've already tried this early in the afternoon. But then it didn't work. Aw well :-) it does now. Thnx for the trouble. Peace

Comment: @Jack—there is no closing [BR](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-br-element.html#the-br-element) tag, therefore, in HTML, the tag is `<br>`. The use of `<br />` is for XHTML. For documents to validate as XHTML, they need `<br />`, but no one actually serves documents as XHTML, even if they are XHTML, unless they want to annoy IE users. Most documents with an XHTML DOCTYPE (on the web) do not validate as XHTML and are served as (also invalid) HTML.

Comment: @Jack—form controls with names have always been available as named properties of the form. The inclusion of IDs as named properties is more recent, but very widely supported.

Comment: @RobG You're right about the named input controls, it's all coming back to me now; I've been using jQuery too much I think =p

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the id and name of the input element on your form is called submit.

This will mask the submit function for the form. Change the name and id and you will be able to use javascript to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the href of the  to '#'. I would guess what is happening is that by clicking on the link, it submits the form and immediately changes the url to the same page you are on cancelling the form submit before it has a chance to go.

Comment: Thanks, such details are important! Peace